# add image to UIButton asynchronously

Tags: ios, image, asynchronous, uibutton

I have the following situation

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But for some reason it seems to be causing some delay in my code, so I want to execute these two lines asynchronously. How might I do that?

Comment: UI changes are made on the Main thread so no async code.

Comment: I imagine I could execute the first line asynchronously and then execute the second on the main thread. The thing is I don't know how to do that. But I guess you are saying both lines must be executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()), ^{ 
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; 
    [btnTwo setImage:btnImage
            forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
});
```

You still have to perform the operation on the main queue because it involves UI elements

Comment: Is it possible to execute the first line asynchronously and then execute the second on the main thread? If yes, how might I do that?

Comment: yes it should be possible: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; }); [btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @user3435374, you can modify your own question and add them in.